# Differnace between "delete p" and "p->~MyClass()"

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            std::cout << "MyClass Constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        ~MyClass()
        {
            std::cout << "MyClass Destructor" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* p = new MyClass();
}
```

What is the difference between 
calling p->~MyClass(); 
OR 
delete p;

Both call the destructor.

Comment: `delete` also returns the allocated memory to the OS. I don't think it is even legal to call the destructor explicitly like this, anyway

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Explicitly calling the destructor is legal, but in this case, you can't explicitly call the destructor, as you need to `delete` the memory, and `delete` calls the destructor, which would call the destructor twice, which is illegal.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If it weren't legal anywhere, the language wouldn't allow you to write it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , Justin  calling destructor usually viable if you are to destroy object created by placement new (i.e., no memory was allocated, object created inside of pre-existing buffer)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `new` operator will:

1. Allocate a chunk of memory.
2. Call the constructor for the class, with `this` pointing at that memory.

`delete` is just the undoing of what `new` does, so it will, by default:

1. Call the destructor with `this` pointing to its memory block.
2. Free the memory block.

You can overload these operators to behave differently, of course.

Comment: "An overloaded `delete` operator would then need to call the destructor manually" That's not how it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Edited accordingly.